# How to make custom character background in Sublime Text 3

Tags: syntax, themes, sublimetext3

tl;dr: how to make text matching a RegEx be highlighted with a bg color in Sublime Text 3?
I am talking about such an effect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx8ue.jpg

Longer read:
I have created a custom theme (.tmTheme) and syntax highlighting (.tmLanguages) they changes text color according to a number of complex regexes for Sublime Text 3, like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAOuX.png

However, I want to change the background color for a given string — "any two or more spaces" in this case. How to do it?

I only found the effect to be connected to blocks in YAML (in syntax_test_block_yaml in the packages), but I don't really see any anything in themes/syntaxes that I can connect to this specific text effect. I am not fluent enough to even know where to start looking.

Comment: Your color scheme (e.g. `Packages\Color Scheme - Default\Monokai.tmTheme`) needs to use a `background` setting for the scope selector. In your example image, that's coming from a predefined scope named `invalid`, which you can see in that color scheme. Your tmLanguage needs to apply that scope (or some other scope you designate) to the areas you want colored that way.

Comment: Oooh, now it seems pretty straighforward – thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to OdatNurd I was able to do what I wanted — basically, created a new object in .tmLanguage called "toomanyspaces" matching two or more spaces. Then in the theme I am using, I added the following:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>toomanyspaces</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>toomanyspaces</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#F92672</string>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#F8F8F0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```